# C++/AS3 winsock send() wont write within else if statment

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, network-programming, winsock2

So, I have a server/client application, at a particular point in the code the client needs to log in to the server, so the server requsts a username and password from the client (and then checks it and  blah blah blah)

heres my code,
client side (AS3)

```
function hwndLogKeyboard(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var allow:Boolean = false;
        var prompt:String;

        socket.writeMultiByte("002", "us-ascii");
        socket.writeByte(0);
        socket.flush();

        while (socket.bytesAvailable == 0)
        {
            trace("waiting for bytes to read");
        }

        prompt = socket.readMultiByte(2, "us-ascii"); //YOU WERE MISSING ); here originally updated as I was formatting, probably just copy paste error
        trace(prompt);
        if (prompt == "UN")//server has prompted for username information, time to send it
          {  
            socket.writeMultiByte(inputname.text, "us-ascii");
            socket.flush();

            prompt = socket.readMultiByte(2, "us-ascii");

            if (prompt == "PW")//server has prompted for password information, time to send it
              {
                 socket.writeMultiByte(inputpass.text, "us-ascii");
                 socket.writeByte(0);
                 socket.flush();
             }
         }

        //more code in here that i have commented out until this issue is resolved

    }
```

and the server side (where im positive the problem is occuring, writtin in C++)

```
if(testr >= 0)
{
    string dataR = string(buffer);
    //data was recived from a client - analize the data to find out what it means
    //signals are in the format "xxx" where 'x' is an int between 0-9

    if(dataR == "001")
    {
        cout << "A new client has connected" << endl;
    }
    else if(dataR == "002")//002 is a client attempting to log-on to the server
    {
        cout << "Client requesting log-on" << endl;
        char recvUsername[16];
        const char requestUsername[3] = "UN";
        char recvPassword[16];
        const char requestPassword[3] = "PW";

        send(Client,requestUsername,3,0);//request username from client

        recv(Client,recvUsername,16,0);//got username, now time to request password

        send(Client,requestPassword,16,0);//request password from client

        recv(Client,recvPassword,3,0);//got password, now time to compare them against current records

        cout << recvUsername << endl << recPassword << endl;
    }
    else if(dataR == "003")
    {
        cout << "A client has used chat" << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "error" << endl << testr << endl << WSAGetLastError << endl;
}
```

At first I thought it was a time issue, that perhaps the client was reading from the buffer before the server can write to it, becuase AS3 crashes becuase the read buffer is empty!

But, here's the trick, I can move my `send(Client,requestUsername,3,0)` to inside the `if(dataR == "001")` block, and it works fine.  The data IS avalible for flash to read when it goes looking for it.  In fact I can put that send statement almost anywhere in my server after the client's socket is created, and it works, just not where i need it to.

That's why i added the

```
while (socket.bytesAvailable == 0)
{                                   
    trace("waiting for bytes to read");
}
```

in the client, so that it would sit a loop until there was data to read, and if that had been the problem, i would have re-wrote some things to avoid that nasty `while` loop from having to be there. What I don't understand is that it goes into an infinite loop, flooding me with trace statements. the sever DOESN'T write the data to the socket, but from anywhere else in the code it will. I get no errors, no compiler complaints, it doesn't go out of scope or anything like that, something is just odd here.

help is much appreciated
-Tyler

still having this problem, it works everywhere else in the code except inside the 'else if' block, im completley stumped.

Comment: Tyler, please format your code, it's unreadable. And in general - try to come up with a small complete example that shows the problem (you are very likely to find your bugs while doing that :)

Comment: I formatted it for you like Nikolai said formatting and cleaning up code will probably help reveal the issue, in the first condition in AS you don't have the flush wrapped in the if statement, you also don't write the 0 byte for the termination in the first case but you do in the second, is this an error?.  If this doesn't help resolve your error it would help if you included trace statements on both server and client for the whole process, including parts that send data for 001 and 003

Comment: @shaunhusain   there must have a few copy/paste errors, cause that flush call is wrapped in my origanal code (i was checking and comparing them), the entire "PW" condition is acually wrapped within the "UN" condition, and the indentation likley got messed up becuase the snippets are already blocked much further over witin the entire code, and i fail terribly at spelling anyways :S

Comment: i did miss the writing of that null charicter, but my code isnt even executing that far so i would have caught it when the time came. as far as tracing, my client only goes as far as the while loop, becuase there is not data in the buffer for it to read, and (before posting the code, i took them out for cleanliness' sake) i had couts/traces in my server and, as far as itss conderned, it re-reads the '002' data as the username and then blocks when it requests the password (unless i hit enter on the client again, which re-send the 002 data and its also read as the password)

Comment: since flash cant read the username request, it never sends the info, and thats where everything comes to a halt.